# How to assign a multiple line string value to a variable with indentation in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script

I want to assign the following multiple line string value to a variable in a shell script with the the exact indentations and lines.

```
Usage: ServiceAccountName LogFile
Where:
      ServiceAccountName - credentials being requested.
      LogFile            - Name of the log file
```

I have been trying to do this following all the suggestions in: [How to assign a string value to a variable over multiple lines while indented?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163898/how-to-assign-a-string-value-to-a-variable-over-multiple-lines-while-indented) 
But with no result. Please suggest.

```
REASON="$(cat <<-EOF
    Usage: ServiceAccountName LogFile
    Where:
      ServiceAccountName - credentials being requested.
      LogFile            - Name of the log file
EOF
)"
echo "$REASON"
```

Here is my script:

GetBatchCredentials.sh

```
if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
   # RETURN INVALID USAGE
   GetBatchCredentials_Result="Error"
   GetBatchCredentials_Reason="$(cat <<-EOF
        Usage: ServiceAccountName LogFile
        Where:
          ServiceAccountName - credentials being requested.
          LogFile            - Name of the log file
    EOF
    )"
else
   //coding...
fi
```

This scripts is called from the following script:

```
. /www/..../scripts/GetBatchCredentials.sh arg1 arg2
if [ "$GetBatchCredentials_Result" != "Success" ]
then
   echo "Error obtaining FTP Credentials"
   echo "$GetBatchCredentials_Reason"
   ret=1
else
   echo "Obtained Credentials"
fi
```

Comment: What output are you getting from the echo?  What you have there works for me.

Comment: I am getting n error: "unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'" and "syntax error: unexpected end of file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script works for me. All I did differently is add #!/bin/sh at top. Then made it executable and ran it. You could also use sh and the name of your original script.

```
#!/bin/sh
REASON="$(cat <<-EOF
Usage: ServiceAccountName LogFile
Where:
      ServiceAccountName - credentials being requested.
      LogFile            - Name of the log file
EOF
)"
echo "$REASON"
```

Comment: I copy pasted the above code from your post to my shell script and it started working. Not sure what made it working though. Thank you.

Comment: @pavanbairu The reason is that the `EOF` end-marker is now not indented and is found. In your original, it is indented and not parsed as the end-marker.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a here-document with a useless cat, what about either

```
REASON="\
Usage: ServiceAccountName LogFile
Where:
      ServiceAccountName - credentials being requested.
      LogFile            - Name of the log file"
```

or

```
REASON="$(printf '%s\n' \
    "Usage: ServiceAccountName LogFile" \
    "Where:" \
    "      ServiceAccountName - credentials being requested." \
    "      LogFile            - Name of the log file")"
```

Comment: ya this is more simpler than having to use extra commands, and it works. Thank you.